# Why is TYPE DATE an error?

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone see why I'm getting this error on this simple command?

```
alter table geno.genotypes add column run_date TYPE DATE;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DATE"
LINE 1: alter table geno.genotypes add column run_date TYPE DATE;
                                                            ^
I mean, how can TYPE DATE be wrong?

TIA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html), I don't believe you should be including the `TYPE` part; that's only when you're *altering* a column (to show that you're altering its type). Try this:

```
alter table geno.genotypes add column run_date DATE;
```